# how resolve Firefox Webdriver firefox_binary error?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I run this code in robot

- robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0
- selenium==4.1.5

```
open page
    [Arguments]  ${serverurl}  ${browser}  ${browserpath}  ${driverpath}
    Create webdriver  ${browser}  firefox_binary=${browserpath}  executable_path=${driverpath}
    Go to  ${serverurl}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

but i have error after run that

TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_binary'

Comment: Your example is correct and should work for Firefox. And only for Firefox, as the parameter `firefox_binary` is a specific parameter for FF only. So, could you please check what value you passed in `${browser}` argument when the error happened?

Comment: And just in case, - pay attention that the driver name should start with capital letter. Should be 'Firefox', not 'firefox'